# How do I write a batch script that will look in two file paths for the executable and then run it

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have written a batch file that looks in two folder paths for an executable and then runs it. I am new to writing batch file and have been told this is sloppy and can be better written with an if / else statements.

```
@echo off
Taskkill /im firefox.exe >nul 2>nul
echo Remove and re-install Mozilla Firefox
"C:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s 
"C:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s
```

So far nothing I have found appears to work;  Here is the last attempt that is not working;

```
@echo off
Taskkill /im firefox.exe >nul 2>nul
echo Remove and re-install Mozilla Firefox

IF exist helper.exe /s ( "C:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\
) else helper.exe /s ( "C:\program files (x86)\Mozilla firefox\uninstall\
)
```

Comment: So you're looking to find `helper.exe` in either folder, then execute it if it exists there?

Comment: The syntax of your `if` attempt is incomplete. Of course you need to put the full path also to `if exist`, just `helper.exe` is not enough. You could also try this: `"%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s`[`||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
@echo off
taskkill /im firefox.exe >nul 2>nul
echo Remove and re-install Mozilla Firefox
if exist "C:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" (
    "C:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s
  ) else (
    "C:\program files (x86)\Mozilla firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s
)
```

but you do not really need the `else` statement:

```
@echo off
taskkill /im firefox.exe >nul 2>nul
echo Remove and re-install Mozilla Firefox
if exist "C:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s
if exist "C:\program files (x86)\Mozilla firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s
```

or

```
"C:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s || "C:\program files (x86)\Mozilla firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /s
```

or even better, find the path to firefox in environment (if installed correctly) and use it's path:

```
@echo off
taskkill /im firefox.exe >nul 2>nul
echo Remove and re-install Mozilla Firefox
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where firefox.exe') do (
    "%%~dpihelper.exe" /s
)
```